# How to create solr document with String type using solarium query

Tags: php, solr, solarium

I' creating solr document via solarium plugin in php.

But the all document is stored `text_general` data type except `id` field. `text_general` is the default datatype in solr system.

My doubt is why `id` field is only to stored string type as default.

And If any possible to add document with `string` type using solarium plugin.

My code part is here,

```
        public function updateQuery() {
            $update = $this->client2->createUpdate();

            // create a new document for the data
            $doc1 = $update->createDocument();
            // $doc1->id = 123;
            $doc1->name = 'value123';
            $doc1->price = 364;

            // and a second one
            $doc2 = $update->createDocument();
            // $doc2->id = 124;
            $doc2->name = 'value124';
            $doc2->price = 340;

            // add the documents and a commit command to the update query
            $update->addDocuments(array($doc1, $doc2));
            $update->addCommit();

            // this executes the query and returns the result
            $result = $this->client2->update($update);

            echo '<b>Update query executed</b><br/>';
            echo 'Query status: ' . $result->getStatus(). '<br/>';
            echo 'Query time: ' . $result->getQueryTime();
        }
```

The result document for the above code is here,

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1562736411330"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "name":["value123"],
        "price":[364],
        "id":"873dfec0-4f9b-4d16-9579-a4d5be8fee85",
        "_version_":1638647891775979520},
      {
        "name":["value124"],
        "price":[340],
        "id":"7228e92d-5ee6-4a09-bf12-78e24bdfa52a",
        "_version_":1638647892102086656}]
  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the field type [defined in the schema](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/defining-fields.html#defining-fields) for your Solr installation. It does not have anything to do with how you're sending data through Solarium.

In the schemaless mode, the `id` field is always set as a string, since a unique field can't be tokenized (well, it can, but it'll give weird, non-obvious errors).

In your case i'd suggest defining the `price` field  as an integer/long field (if it's integers all the way) and the `name` field as a string field. Be aware that `string` fields only generate hits on exact matches, so in your case you'd have to search for `value124` with exact casing to get a hit.

You can also adjust the `multiValued` property of the field when you define the fields explicitly. That way you get only the string back in the JSON structure instead of an array containing the string.

Comment: Yes. I already know how to change schema in manually. Now my question is `How to change field type or set field type dynamically using solarium plugin`

Comment: You can't. The issue requesting [support for the Schema API is still open](https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium/issues/255). You can make manual JSON requests yourself [using the Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html) or submit a PR to implement it in Solarium.